# How to call multiple functions as arguments inside another function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, args, keyword-argument

I am struggling with the below exercise:

Arguments to particular functions should be passed to function_results_sum as keywords argumentsand it should look like FUNCTION_NAME=ARGUMENTS

The function_results_sum should return sum of all the results received after running each passing function with arguments

If the function has no arguments, the arguments shouldn't be passed to function_results_sum

If the function takes 1 argument, as keyword argument int will be passed to function_results_sum (for example one_arg_function_name=2)

If function takes more than 1 argument - tuple is expected to be passed (for example two_args_function_name=(1, 2) )

How it should work like:
 1st example
 functions signatures:
 def no_arg()
 def one_arg(a)
 def multiple_args(a, b, c, e, f)

calling function_results_sum:
 function_results_sum(
     no_arg, one_arg, multiple_args,
     one_arg=23,
     multiple_args=(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
 )

2nd example of how to call function_results_sum:
 function_results_sum(
     no_arg, one_arg, multiple_args,
     one_arg=-1245,
     multiple_args=(45, 65, 76, 123456, 111.222)
)

! Use **name** attribute on the function object !

This is what I came up with, however I do not know why I get the result as the addresses of the cells where the outputs are stored:

## Console output:

```
<function ident at 0x00000288C0A72048> <function no_arg at 
0x00000288C0A6BF28> 
<function mult at 0x00000288C0A720D0>
```

My implementation:

```
def function_results_sum(*args, **kwargs):
    return [*args]
def no_arg():
    return 5
def ident(x):
    return x
def mult(x, y):
    return x * y
a = function_results_sum(ident, no_arg, mult, ident = 2, mult = (2, 3))
print(a)
```

Comment: Have you read https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-on-defining-functions?

Comment: I have read, and the way I used *args and **kwargs is what I came up with :<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hint that calls the one-argument function:

```
def function_results_sum(*args, **kwargs):
    func = args[0]
    function_name = func.__name__
    parameter = kwargs[function_name]
    return func(parameter)

def ident(x):
    return x

a = function_results_sum(ident,ident=2)
print(a)
```

`args` will contain a list of the functions to be called, and `kwargs` contains the list of parameters using the function names as keys.  See if you can figure out how to call the three types of functions.